# JPA Repository method List<Integer> returns result as List<BigDecimal> why?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have next method in JPA Repository kartDao:

```
@Query(value = "select t.k_lsk_id from SCOTT.KART t ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Integer> findAllKlskId();
```

When I try to fetch it using:

```
List<Integer> someLst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
someLst.add(12); // my Integer value
someLst.addAll(kartDao.findAllKlskId());
```

I see in debugger that someList contains both Integer and BigDecimal types:

[image]

But how it happens? My someList is List type!!
Can't understand, help me))

**upd1**
In Oracle database the k_lsk_id type is Number:

[image]

Comment: Type Erasure in Java. After compiling the Java file, it's the List whatever you declare List as List<Integer> or  List<BigDecimal>. You should check your k_lsk_id column definition and make sure the k_lsk_id can be represented by Integer.

Comment: pls see my upd1

Comment: Oracle number(p, s): Where p is the precision and s is the scale.For example, number(7,2) is a number that has 5 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal.
So, maybe you can change the type of K_LSK_ID to Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is [this line of code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/2d72f8f3239b1fb0672360a80b0ca7afba9c5c4c/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryExecution.java#L107) I think. 
It tries to convert the result of the query execution.
If it fails to find a converter it just returns the original unconverted result.

The converter used is essentially a [`DefaultConversionService`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/DefaultConversionService.java) which doesn't support any convertions from `BigDecimal`.

UPDATE: I looked a little more into this, and it seems that the problem is not so much that the conversion service can't convert `BigDecimal`, but that the requested target type is simply `List`.

I [opened an issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1505) and will look into it.

Comment: Looks like the problem is a little more involved. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

Number return decimal value form the DB side.

you should have to change the number to Integer